# There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I installed the "Contact Form 7" plugin in WordPress and created a form.

When i click on the submit button, the following error appears:

> There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question and more suited for [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 3):

Yeah! Got the solution.

Have to provide mail id which is belongings to domain, in Mail tab..

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further ? Perhaps a screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

I got this message too, when trying to submit test data through my form. When I changed the value entered in the form's Email field from test@example.com to a real email address, then the form started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Please enable in the sendemail on ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt-get install sendmail
$ sudo sendmailconfig
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your message type? the error message **There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.** may appear in Red border or Orange Border and each type of error has different fixes

(for more detail step by step you can refer this tutorial: https://wooexplorer.com/how-to-fix-contact-form-7-there-was-an-error-trying-to-send-your-message-please-try-again-later)

**Solution for Red border error message**
[image]

=> Install and enable `php mail()` function

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
service apache2 restart
```

If you are using shared hosting then you ask your hosting provider to enable this function for you
In case they don't allow php mail() function, try to use SMTP to send mail (recommended)
You can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/

**Solution for Orange border error message**
[image]
With my experience dealing with There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later, error message in orange border, this error happens when the reCAPTCHA module is not working properly on your site
To get new reCAPTCHA key, go to: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create and apply this to Contactform7 in **Contact => Integration**

Answer (score 1):

I've the solution. Install Flamingo plugin then send a message then go to flamingo - inbound messages and check the spam log. In my case it was because I'm using some disallowed words in my form. To see your disallowed words go to settings - discussion - disallowed comments

Answer (score 0):

A simple Trick to solve this error is-:
in the To field, you have to put `info<youremail@gmail.com>`
make sure to try to put Gmail id this works for me.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

## How to Add contact form 7 in Wordpress

Step1: Install Contact Form 7 plugin.

Step2 : Create new form with appropriate setup and configure it with mail.

Step3 : Copy the shortcode of that form and paste it where it is needed.

### IF THIS IS NOT WORKING then FOLLOW NEXT STEPS

Step 1 : Create email in Email Accounts in hPanel or cPanel

Step 2 : Install Easy WP SMTP plugin and Go to setting of Easy WP SMTP

---

### SMTP CONFIGURATION SETTING EXAMPLE :—

From Email Address: info@example.com

From Name: Example

Reply-To Email Address: info@example.com (Optional)

BCC Email Address (Optional) -- This email address will be used in the 'BCC' field of the outgoing emails. Use this option carefully since all your outgoing emails from this site will add this address to the BCC field. You can also enter multiple email addresses (comma separated).

SMTP Host: smtp.hostinger.com (just an example)

Type of Encryption: SSL/TLS --For most servers SSL/TLS is the recommended option.

SMTP Port: 465

SMTP Authentication: Yes -- This options should always be checked 'Yes'

SMTP Username: info@example.com -- The username to login to your mail server

SMTP Password: ***********  --- The password to login to your mail server

### If you want to add reCAPTCHA

Step 1 : Install reCAPTCHA v2 for Contact Form 7

Step 2 : Go to Contact —> Integration —> reCAPTCHA —> setup integration, Paste site key and secret key , Get it from “https://www.google.com/recaptcha” or instructions given there…

#### Note : If we deactivate or remove reCAPTCHA plugin, then we have also remove Api Keys that includes site key and secret key. (Important).

THANK YOU